# enterprise architect scripting: missed method in java api eaapi.jar

Tags: java, enterprise-architect

In the Reference of the Enterprise Architect Object Model I found the class `Element`:
http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.3/automation/element2.html

The class `Element` contains the attribute `IsComposite`. I use the Java API (eaapi.jar) of Sparx Systems and can't find the Setter for this attribute (`myElement.SetIsComposite(true)` isn't possible).

Does anybody know a solution for this problem? For example an updated lib of eaapi.jar or a workaround?

Regards,
Phil

Comment: If the attribute is public (it is also marked as read/write), just use it straight away: `myElement.IsComposite = true;`

Comment: Getter and setter methods are just a general approach of using OOP, but in some cases they are not necessary.

Comment: Hello Jari, thank you for your fast comment. I had already try to set this attribute in this way. But it seems, that the attribute isn't public. For other boolean attributes of the class Element are Getter&Setter available:/ I guess that the author of the library forget this:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EA's Java API is a wrapper for the underlying COM API, which is what's documented in the help file. The Java version is generally a step or two behind the COM version.

It would appear that this method has been left out of the Java API. Other properties in the COM classes have getters/setters in the Java API, but this one doesn't. The same is true in version 10.0.1009.

In EA [11.0.1105](http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/history.html#1105) (the first general release of EA 11), `Element.SetCompositeDiagram()` was added, but this too seems to be limited to the COM API: reverse-engineering `eaapi.jar` reveals no corresponding method.

From here there would appear to be three alternatives open to you:

1. Report the issue to Sparx Systems and ask them to add the relevant methods to the Java API.
2. Rewrite your code in C# to make use of the full API.
3. Use the undocumented `Repository.Execute()` method to manipulate the underlying database directly.

An element's "compositeness" is represented by the value 8 in the `t_object.NType` column, but this column is overloaded, that is to say the interpretation of its value depends on other columns as well, and furthermore is undocumented. So this is not a good solution if you want maintainability.

If you want to go this way, first add the diagram and then do something like this:

```
repository.Execute("update t_object set NType = 8 where Object_ID = " +
                   element.ElementID);
```

I think that would work, but I haven't tested it. If there are more than one diagrams in the element, I think the first one gets picked. But all this is essentially guesswork, so if you want to build something that you know will work, switch to C#.